# Entity Framework Load() method doesn't load everything

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a problem

I have a table with 44839 records

But when I try to load my table through EF with this code:

```
dbContext = new MyDbContext("MyContext");

dbContext.SalesRegister.Load();

BindingList<SalesRegister> db =dbContext.SalesRegister.Local.ToBindingList();

gridControl.DataSource = db;

bsiRecordsCount.Caption = "RECORDS : " + db.Count;
```

I only get 16311 records

But when I use this I get all my records

```
dbContext = new MyDbContext("MyContext");

List<SaleRegister> db = dbContext.SalesRegister.SqlQuery("select * from  vwSalesRegister").ToList();

gridControl.DataSource = db;

bsiRecordsCount.Caption = "RECORDS : " + db.Count;
```

Why is this happening??

Comment: @Ivan alright, sounds logical, thanks for that.

Comment: Looking at the name prefix "vw", I guess this is mapped db view. Have you defined a proper PK?

Comment: @IvanStoev makes total sense!!! yes you were right! I totally forgot to define the PK in the database side. That's the solution to this strange behaviour. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the solution for this was really simple!! Make sure to define the PK on both sides (code & database). Thanks to @IvanStoev